# Integrating Wagtail Into Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, wagtail

I have confirmed that my Django project works perfectly. However, I am interested in integrating wagtail CMS into the project.

I am following [Wagtail documentation](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/getting_started/integrating_into_django.html), for proper guidance.

However, on clicking `python manage.py runserver`. I get the error shown below.

Wagtail Integration Error:

[image]

I have removed all my created apps from `INSTALLED_APP`, I have also removed them from the available URLs.

Unfortunately, non of the above method fixed the problem for me.

Your guide on how to fix this type of error will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure of the steps you have taken. If I understand your question correctly, you added Wagtail to your Django site and then removed it again. But you are still getting an error message related to `wagtailcore.Site`. If that is the sequence of events, then I would say you did not fully remove all mentions of Wagtail from your code. Can you reset your code to the point before you added Wagtail using version control (git or whatever)? Or, if you have made other changes you don't want to lose, perhaps search your code for any other mentions of "wagtail".

---

If you would like to carry on integrating Wagtail into your site, please repeat the install steps and then post any errors you receive at that point so we can try to help. (And by the way, posting the error message inline as a code snippet makes it a lot easier for us to see the error at the same time as the description of how you got there.